# Increase label max length

Tags: 8, forms

The default max length for all labels of all field types is 128. The DB can handle 255. So no schema change. How can I change the default max length to 250?

I've seen this module https://www.drupal.org/project/remove_field_label_length_limit

> Removes field label length limit (which is 128 characters). The module
>   supports entity field labels, field group labels, and views field
>   labels.

it was working on Drupl7 very well. but there is no version for Drupal 8.

I'm looking for a way to increase all Label length in a specified content type.

Comment: Did you check the issue queue? https://www.drupal.org/project/remove_field_label_length_limit/issues/2793035

Comment: @Clive yes, I'll try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [Change Label Length limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/label_length_limit) module.

**it lets users change the maximum limit of label fields.**